# Ajax call on Keyup function

Tags: jquery, ajax, onkeyup

i have this situation:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
</form>
<div id="risultato" style="max-width: 80%;"></div>
```

Ajax Call on Keyup

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var final = "1";
$("#test").keyup(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../templates/g5_helium/html/com_users/registration/ajax.php",
data: "final=" + final,
dataType: "html",
success: function(msg){$("#risultato").html(msg);},
error: function(){alert("Error");}
});
});
});
```

File Ajax.php

```
if ($_POST['final'] == 1) {echo 'Yes';} else {echo 'No';}
```

But it doesn't work..

Any ideas? :(

Comment: `$("text")` is looking for an element `<text></text>` that does not exist ... use id selector `$("#test")`. This is simply a selector typo

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the listener firing? Is the AJAX request failing? Is the PHP raising an error? Is your success handler behaving the way you think it is?

Comment: @charlietfl i'm trying  $("#test").keyup(function() but nothing

Comment: @WillardSolutions Call doesn't work. Usually, if i have error on call i callback with error function() and i have  an alert.

Comment: So open your browser dev tools network tab and check if request is made and what is returned if anything and what status is.  Requires some very basic debugging and providing more troubleshooting details

Comment: Fix the issue noted by @charlietfl, then open devtools and watch the request to see where it's failing

Comment: @charlietfl  debug say Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (testphp:154)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ testphp:154
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3

Comment: But i'm using the same function (onkeypress apart) for making a call

Comment: That error shows you are using *"slim"* version of jQuery which does not include `$.ajax` API. Code in question shows using full version. Also in future it helps a lot to mention errors in the question

Comment: Yep. Sorry, i'm a beginner. Now i understand why...... :(